# Android - detect how big bitmap can be created without crash

Tags: android, bitmap, bigdata, size

I work on dungeon mapping tool which supports world map of infinite size. Whole world map is infinite grid, in every it's cell is small map. I want export world map to bitmap, but of course this is impossible, because can be of unknown size. I must export it in smaller bitmaps and I like to ask, how to detect how big bitmaps I can create without crash.

Comment: just make a loop where you create a bitmap with increasing resolution. But... it depends on the device and whats happening further on the device too.

Comment: Ok, I just calculated optimal resolution what I want achieve. It is 1600x1600 pixels, what is roughly 10MB of memory. Question is how often I will fall to out of memory

Comment: 10MB is not much if several GB's are available.